# После require_once() откуда-то возникает единичка

Tags: php, require

Очень странная ситуация, глупая, но не решаемая уже много часов.

Вопрос 1 - как убрать единичку?

Вопрос 2 - присоединяется посторонний код, откуда он берется?

Вот результат. На Скрин 1 содержимое файла index_text.php
Здесь не должно быть единички.
[image]

Потому что код следующий:
скрин2, скрин3
[image: Самый простой код]
[image: Присоединяем девятку]

Т.е единичка появляется в момент присоединения файла header.php. Содержимое этого файла тоже не содержит единичку.

И скрин4 – что это такое? (Возможно не связано с первым вопросом)
Этого нигде нет в коде. Причем на этом же хостинге в других сайтах все ок работает.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Полдня не понимаю уже...((
Пробовал другие функции присоединения: require, include. Результат тот же.
Пробовал разные кавычки. На скрине для функции они одинарные, но всегда стоят двойные.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: скажи, а echo тут зачем?

Comment: 4 echo, 4 цифры. Всё бьётся)

Comment: Открыть мануал запрещено религией?

Comment: echo просто для примера. ))

Comment: ну тогда не удилвляйся что тебе и выводит этот пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот документация по [require/include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

В общих чертах. Выражение **require_once()** включает и выполняет код из файла. При этом само это выражение возвращает (но не выводит) либо `FALSE` при ошибке, либо `1` при успешном включении. В данном случае ваше `require_once('...')` возвращает `1`. И ваше `echo` перед этой конструкцией эту единицу и выводит.

Comment: Точно! Да, теперь это очевидно. Спасибо большое за линк и за то, что разжевали.